# convert the for loop with index using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to C# language, I have started learning LINQ in that
So I just want to convert the code using linq. Is there any way to do. The current implementation is not a stylish one.

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (int index = 0; index < contentList.Count; index++)
{
    list.Add(MyClass.GetCorrespondence(module, index));
}
return list;
```

Comment: "Stylish" is not something we strive for in software dev - readable, maintainable, bugfree - all good. I suspect your code probably has all 3!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was checking, whether I can re-write the same code using linq. like 

      return new List<>{
      MyClass.getCorrespondence(module, (i => { something})
      }.ToList();

Comment: We understand your question. However we only want to mention that there is no need to use linq in your case, it won´t bring you **any** benefit. Instead it makes your code harder to read and due to debugger-limitations even harder to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* write it like this:

```
var list = contentList.Select((_, i) => MyClass.GetCorrespondence(module, i)).ToList();
```

or like this

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0,contentList.Count).Select(i => MyClass.GetCorrespondence(module, i)).ToList();
```

But, honestly, dont do either! Your code is perfectly readable as it is.

Answer (score 3):

If you must use LINQ for this then you can use the overload for [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) which "projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index." e.g:

```
list.AddRange(contentList.Select((c, index) => MyClass.GetCorrespondence(c, index));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

If you're desperate to do it with Linq then you could try:

```
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, contentList.Count).Select(index => MyClass.GetCorrespondence(module, index)))
```

or:

```
list = Enumerable.Range(0, contentList.Count).Select(index => MyClass.GetCorrespondence(module, index)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

this method work:

```
var result= contentList.Select((paramter,index)=>MyClass.GetCorrespondence(module,index)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the `ForEach` LINQ statement.

```
contentList.ForEach(x => list.Add(MyClass.GetCorrespondence(module, x)));
```

EDIT: Any reason why this was down voted?